# console.log uses alerts in ie9 with developer tools open

Tags: javascript, console, internet-explorer-9

I am using IE9 and trying to debug some javascript.  I read all over the place that `console.log()` will actually log to the console rather than puking up alerts when developer tools are open.

However, I have developer tools open and console.log is still giving alerts.  What am I missing?

---

- Browser Mode: IE9 Compat Mode
- Document Mode: IE8 Standards

Comment: You'll have to provide a test case, because I have **never** (even with developer tools in IE6) had `console.log()` create an `alert()`.  From all my experience, if tools aren't open, `console.log()` throws an error because `console` is undefined unless the tools are open.

Answer (score 1):

I would look to see if console.log is being redefined somewhere in your JS.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` won't `alert()` anything ... I think you are using some custom console.log-function in your code. However I'd always suggest to use those tiny functions which are shipped with html5boilerplate:

```
// usage: log('inside coolFunc', this, arguments);
// paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/
window.log = function f(){ log.history = log.history || []; log.history.push(arguments); if(this.console) { var args = arguments, newarr; args.callee = args.callee.caller; newarr = [].slice.call(args); if (typeof console.log === 'object') log.apply.call(console.log, console, newarr); else console.log.apply(console, newarr);}};

// make it safe to use console.log always
(function(a){function b(){}for(var c="assert,count,debug,dir,dirxml,error,exception,group,groupCollapsed,groupEnd,info,log,markTimeline,profile,profileEnd,time,timeEnd,trace,warn".split(","),d;!!(d=c.pop());){a[d]=a[d]||b;}})
(function(){try{console.log();return window.console;}catch(a){return (window.console={});}}());
```

Include them, use them and you'll not have any errors caused by your debugging output in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that `console.log` has been rewritten by some script on the page. I'd test if this `alert` behavior appeared on all sites or just this one you are currently testing.  (If it does happen everywhere, maybe `console.log` is being rewritten by a browser add-on.)

Try using `console.warn` instead (or even `console.error`, in a pinch) -- perhaps that will still behave as expected.  It's a nice sanity check, and it can still get you debugging output if you never get `console.log` working.